# npm run build-storybook fails with "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (20:25)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, storybook

I am trying to setup Storybook from scratch for a new project. I am hitting a wall and finding no useful information online around a babel/webpack issue that appears during build.

Note that I am able to correctly run Storybook locally, this issue only happens during build time.

The project has no webpack.config.js file as none came via the following commands.

How to diagnose further and fix the build issues?

Initial Set-up

- React Boilerplate: https://react-boilerplate.github.io/react-boilerplate-cra-template/
- Storybook out of the box set-up: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/install

No issue running storybook locally

> npm run storybook --debug-webpack

```
> react-boilerplate@4.0.0 storybook C:\Users\micro\Documents\GitHub\storybook
> start-storybook -p 6006

> info @storybook/react v6.1.11 info info => Loading presets info =>
> Loading presets info => Loading 1 config file in "./.storybook" info
> => Loading 7 other files in "./.storybook" info => Adding stories defined in ".storybook\main.js" info => Loading custom Webpack config
> (full-control mode). 11% building 9/21 modules 12 active
> ...s\@storybook\addon-docs\dist\frameworks\react\config.js B
> rowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm
> update` webpack built e975d6d02e1a4b82c9e2 in 29152ms
```

But when trying to build it, it fails:

> npm run build-storybook

```
> react-boilerplate@4.0.0 build-storybook C:\Users\micro\Documents\GitHub\storybook
> build-storybook

info @storybook/react v6.1.11
info
info => Cleaning outputDir C:\Users\micro\Documents\GitHub\storybook\storybook-static
info => Building manager..
info => Loading manager config..
info => Loading presets
info => Compiling manager..
info => Manager built (20 s)
info => Building preview..
info => Loading preview config..
info => Loading presets
info => Loading 1 config file in "./.storybook"
info => Loading 7 other files in "./.storybook"
info => Adding stories defined in ".storybook\main.js"
info => Loading custom Webpack config (full-control mode).
info => Compiling preview..
info => Preview built (14 s)
WARN ./stories/Header.stories.js 17:25
WARN Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:25)
WARN File was processed with these loaders:
WARN  * ./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
WARN  * ./node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/index.js
WARN You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
WARN | };
WARN |
WARN > const Template = args => <Header {...args} />;
WARN |
WARN | export const LoggedIn = Template.bind({});;
WARN  @ \.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$ (./stories sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$) ./Header.stories.js  
WARN  @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
WARN  @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
WARN ./stories/Page.stories.js 18:25
WARN Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:25)
WARN File was processed with these loaders:
WARN  * ./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
WARN  * ./node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/index.js
WARN You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
WARN | };
WARN |
WARN > const Template = args => <Page {...args} />;
WARN |
WARN | export const LoggedIn = Template.bind({});;
WARN  @ \.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$ (./stories sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$) ./Page.stories.js    
WARN  @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
WARN  @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
WARN ./stories/Button.stories.js 20:25
WARN Module parse failed: Unexpected token (20:25)
WARN File was processed with these loaders:
WARN  * ./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
WARN  * ./node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/index.js
WARN You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
WARN | };
WARN |
WARN > const Template = args => <Button {...args} />;
WARN |
WARN | export const Primary = Template.bind({});;
WARN  @ \.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$ (./stories sync ^\.(?:(?:^|[\\/]|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$) ./Button.stories.js  
WARN  @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
WARN  @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
WARN asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
WARN This can impact web performance.
WARN Assets:
WARN   vendors~main.d6c409068a146daf5220.bundle.js (3.8 MiB)
WARN entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
WARN Entrypoints:
WARN   main (3.82 MiB)
WARN       runtime~main.d6c409068a146daf5220.bundle.js
WARN       vendors~main.d6c409068a146daf5220.bundle.js
WARN       main.d6c409068a146daf5220.bundle.js
WARN
WARN webpack performance recommendations:
WARN You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
WARN For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
info => Output directory: C:\Users\micro\Documents\GitHub\storybook\storybook-static
```

.storybook/main.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "storybook-addon-designs",
    "storybook-addon-performance/register",
  ],
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),
    },
  },
}
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
        loose: true,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'styled-components',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import', { loose: true }],
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      only: ['app'],
      plugins: [
        'lodash',
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
      ],
    },
    test: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        'dynamic-import-node',
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

packages.json

```
    {
  "name": "react-boilerplate",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "A highly scalable, offline-first foundation with the best DX and a focus on performance and best practices",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=5",
    "node": ">=8.15.1"
  },
  "author": "Max Stoiber",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "analyze:clean": "rimraf stats.json",
    "preanalyze": "npm run analyze:clean",
    "analyze": "node ./internals/scripts/analyze.js",
    "extract-intl": "node ./internals/scripts/extract-intl.js",
    "npmcheckversion": "node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js",
    "preinstall": "npm run npmcheckversion",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:clean",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ./build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "start:tunnel": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ENABLE_TUNNEL=true node server",
    "start:production": "npm run test && npm run build && npm run start:prod",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "presetup": "npm i chalk shelljs",
    "setup": "node ./internals/scripts/setup.js",
    "clean": "shjs ./internals/scripts/clean.js",
    "clean:all": "npm run analyze:clean && npm run test:clean && npm run build:clean",
    "generate": "plop --plopfile internals/generators/index.js",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:css",
    "lint:css": "stylelint app/**/*.js",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern internals/scripts",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern internals/scripts --fix",
    "lint:js": "npm run lint:eslint -- . ",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "pretest": "npm run test:clean && npm run lint",
    "test:clean": "rimraf ./coverage",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll",
    "coveralls": "cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls",
    "prettify": "prettier --write",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "> 1%",
    "IE 10"
  ],
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "npm run lint:eslint:fix",
      "git add --force"
    ],
    "*.json": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add --force"
    ]
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint:staged",
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "6.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.1",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.1.0",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.0",
    "immer": "3.0.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "6.0.0-beta",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-redux": "7.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.2",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "8.0.0",
    "sonarjs": "^1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.11",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "chromatic": "^5.5.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
    "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "coveralls": "3.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.5.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.6.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.7.1",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "6.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
    "ngrok": "3.1.1",
    "node-plop": "0.18.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "offline-plugin": "5.0.6",
    "plop": "2.3.0",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "6.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "storybook-addon-designs": "^5.4.2",
    "storybook-addon-performance": "^0.13.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.6.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.3",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "4.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the react template uses a webpack config which is in a different directory. Replacing the build directory **app** by **stories** fixed it.

**internals\webpack\webpack.base.babel.js**

```
...
resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'stories'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
  },
...
```